# File is being used by another process except that it's not

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, linq, parsing

I'm currently working on a utility to parse  multiple `xml` files and write the results to a `csv` file. On the second last line(of code) I get the error:

```
The process cannot access the file 'W:\SRC\hDefML\myExcelFile.csv' because it is being used by another process.'.
```

Can someone please help me because I have no idea what's wrong, the file isn't being used by anything else and it's driving me crazy?

Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace GenNameUtility
{
    class NameGenerator
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            var files = from file in       Directory.GetFiles("W:\\SRC\\hDefMl\\1.0\\Instrument_Files") orderby file 
        ascending select file;

        StringBuilder sb_report = new StringBuilder();

        string delimiter = ",";

        sb_report.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, "Module", "Generator(s)"));

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

            Console.Write("The HDefML file for {0} contains these EEPROM Generators:", filename);

            XDocument hdefml = XDocument.Load(file);

                var GeneratorNames = from b in hdefml.Descendants("Generators") select new
        {
           name = (string)b.Element("GeneratorName") 

        }.ToString();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in GeneratorNames)
        {
            Console.Write("  GeneratorName is: {0}", GeneratorNames);
            sb_report.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, filename, GeneratorNames));

        var hdef = File.Create(@"W:\SRC\hDefML\myExcelFile.csv").ToString();
        File.WriteAllText(hdef, sb.ToString());
        }          
     }
        Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) will create a file for you so there's no need to use `File.Create` beforehand.

```
File.WriteAllText(@"W:\SRC\hDefML\myExcelFile.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Your `File.Create` stream seems to be holding the lock on the file which is why `File.WriteAllText` is throwing the error.

If you need to use `File.Create` you can use a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) to write it out.

```
using(var fs = File.Create(@"W:\SRC\hDefML\myExcelFile.csv"))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    sw.Write(sb.ToString());                  
}
```

as a side note, the above `using` format is the same as doing

```
using(var fs = File.Create(@"W:\SRC\hDefML\myExcelFile.csv"))
{
   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
   {
      sw.Write(sb.ToString());                  
   }
}
```

so you can use whichever you find more readable.

Comment: This is good to know but creating the file first seems to be better in this instance. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason No problem, I've updated my answer. As others have suggested, you should use a `using` statement. However, because you're using a `FileStream`, you can't simply write text to it. You can use a `StreamWriter` to write the text for you into the FileStream.

Comment: Also, your `foreach` loop is calling `Create` each time which will overwrite the previous file that was created. You could use [File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx) instead or change the name of the file being created in the loop.

Comment: Is the fact that the loop is overwriting each file the reason that when I run it and then look at the file there is nothing there?

Comment: If the value of `sb.ToString()` in the last item in the loop is empty then yes, that would likely be the reason.

Answer (score 5):

You need to close the file after you have written to it. See `using`.

Also it would be better to open the file before the loop and close it thereafter.

Comment: When I do I get an error saying cannot convert FileStream to string? Also thanks for the help. @Simon

Comment: File.WriteAllText needs the following parameters: Filename and text to be written. You've kind of mixed several ways of writing data. I would recommend doing this: `using (StreamWriter sw=File.CreateText(@"...")) { foreach(...) { ... sw.Write(sb.ToString()); ... } }`

Answer (score 2):

The file is being used by another process... but the process is actually yours.

`File.Create` returns a `FileStream`. You're opening the file.. writing to it.. but not closing it. When the new iteration comes around.. the file is still open.

You can try something like this:

```
using (var file = File.Create(@"W:\SRC\hDefML\myExcelFile.csv")) {
    // write content here using file
} // this closes the file automatically.
```

As suggested though, I would wrap the above outside of the loop, so you're not constantly opening and closing the file.